# package alanning:roles at 1.0.6 is incompatible with Meteor 0.9.0 or later

Tags: meteor, package

My meteor version is 1.4.1.1 and have used my personalised package in which I am using `alanning:roles` (`api.use(alanning:roles)`)

I am getting the following errors on my command prompt:

```
W20161111-16:24:34.950(5.5)? (STDERR) The package mizzao:user-status at 0.2.0 is incompatible with Meteor 0.9.0 or later. 
W20161111-16:24:35.473(5.5)? (STDERR) If a new, compatible version of this package exists, running 'meteor update' should cause you to update. 
W20161111-16:24:35.474(5.5)? (STDERR) The package alanning:roles at 1.0.6 is incompatible with Meteor 0.9.0 or later. 
W20161111-16:24:35.474(5.5)? (STDERR) If a new, compatible version of this package exists, running 'meteor update' should cause you to update. 
=> Started your app.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you are declaring API compatibility with `0.9.0`. How about declaring a later version (e.g, `api.versionsFrom('1.3.0');`)? Have you tried defining a version? `api.use('alanning:roles@1.2.15');`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply i tried meteor update alanning:roles and it worked for me. I am closing this question

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer simply write below command in your meteor project command prompt:

meteor update alanning:roles